# Two adjacent spans: One is vertically center aligned, the other is not. Why?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

In the following SSCCE, I applied a CSS property `vertical-align:middle;` to the `.innerContainer` div. It has two spans: one containing the `ALPHA BRAVO CHARLIE` text, and the other containing the `SUBSCRIBE NOW` text.

The `#firstSpan` seems to be vertically aligned in the middle. The `#secondSpan` doesn't. **Why?**

**[JsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/6nk8x01L/2/)**

**I want the `#secondSpan` span to also be aligned in the middle vertically. How do I do that?**

*HTML:*

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="innerContainer">
    <span class="firstSpan">Alpha Bravo Charlie</span>
    <span class="secondSpan">Subscribe now</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
.container {
    margin-bottom:0px;  
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
.innerContainer {
    background-color: rgb(74, 72, 72); 
    padding: 30px 10px 30px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    /* vertical-align: middle; */
}
.firstSpan {
    font-family: Oxygen, sans-serif ;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.secondSpan {
    margin: 0 40px 0 40px; 
    padding: 15px;
    background-color:green; 
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    font-weight: bolder; 
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

*Screenshot:*

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `vertical-align` apply to the element itself not to the content, try

```
.innerContainer > span {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**[UpdatedDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/6nk8x01L/6/)**

In case your browser window isn't wide enough to show the aligned text, here's [the same demo with some of the text taken out](http://jsfiddle.net/6nk8x01L/8/).

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6nk8x01L/7/)

```
 .innerContainer span{ vertical-align: middle; 
    display:inline-block; }
```

vertical align make it align like you want and inline-block prevent breaking off subscribe now